# Bounded second derivative also bounds the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds, greens-theorem, mean-value-theorem

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
> $f(x,y)=xg(y)-yg(x)$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
> such that $g\in C^2$, $g(0)=0$ and $|g''(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in
> > \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove that if $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]$, then $|f(x,y)|\leq C$.

I don't know how the second derivative being bounded coul bound the function.
The function $f(x,y)=xg(y)-yg(x)$ makes me think of Green's theorem, but that does not get us closer to the second derivative.

$$\int \int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}xg(y)-yg(x)dxdy=\int_\partial \frac{x^2}{2}g(y)dy+\frac{y^2}{2}g(x)dx$$
I also tried to use Taylor Polynomial with Lagrange Remainder, but we are missing any information about the first derivative of $g$, which appears when calculating the remainder.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I would suggest you use the (single-variable) Mean Value Theorem *twice* to bound $|f(x,y)|=|f(x,y)-f(x,0)|$. No integrals should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the assumption, $x,y \in [0,1]$. Assume, WLOG, that $x \leq y$. By the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists r,s,t \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
|f(x,y)| &= |xg(y) - yg(x)| \\
&= |xg(y) - xg(0) - yg(x) + yg(0)| \\
&= |x(g(y) - g(0)) - y(g(x) - g(0))| \\
&= |xy g'(ty) - xyg'(sx)| \\
&= xy|g'(ty) - g'(sx)| \\
&= xy|(rty + (1-r)sx)g''(rty + (1-r)sx)| \\
&= [rt xy^2 + (1-r)sx^2y] |g''(rty + (1-r)sx)| \\
&\leq [rtxy^2 + (1-r)sx^2 y] C \\
&\leq C.
\end{align*}
$$

We apply the Mean Value Theorem thrice:

1. $s$ is applying the Mean Value Theorem to $g$ on the interval $[0, x]$,
2. $t$ is applying the Mean Value Theorem to $g$ on the interval $[0,y]$, and
3. $r$ is applying the Mean Value Theorem to $g'$ on the interval $[sx, ty]$ .

Note the last inequality is true because $x,y,r,s,t \in [0,1]$, by assumption, and $[0,1]$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: You can make a bit simpler by following the suggestion in my comment to the OP. Then you need only one application of MVT to $g$, one to say $g(u)/u = g’(\xi)$, and one to $g’$.

Comment: Sure but $g(u)/u = g'(\xi)$ has $\xi$ depending upon $u$, so you would still need $\xi_x$ and $\xi_y$ for the first application, no?

Comment: No, because I’m looking at $f(x,y)-f(x,0)$. :) This comes from the common game of looking at $f(x,y)-f(0,0)=\big(f(x,y)-f(x,0)\big)+\big(f(x,0)-f(0,0)\big)$.

Comment: I understand, thanks for enlightening me! That's definitely more elegant!